# TidHTTPClient raising Timeout Exception on code 304

Tags: delphi, indy

I am writing an hybrid (web/desktop) software and it happens to be loaded of synchronizations between the two modules.

I am trying to use as much HTTP Codes as possible in the communication between them.

In the server side I have Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9 (if that matters for this question). In the desktop side I am using Delphi 7 and Indy 9.0.50.

When I try to get updated data and there is nothing new in the server side, my server API returns code 304 (not modified) wich I understand as being the most apropriate code in this case. But the indy component (TidHTTPClient) raises a Timeout Exception (specificaly EIdReadTimeout). And it actually "waits" for a few seconds, causing a delay I am not comfortable with.

Is this behaviour ok? Am I using an unapropriate HTTP code? Is there a way to avoid the component from waiting for data once it will never come for sure?

Comment: is this exception raised while running the app in the IDE? if so, then if you run your TIdHTTPClient.GET between a try..except and the IDE is not running, you should not get an exception...

Comment: I see two problems. First, response 304 is for "conditional GET" requests; are you sending a conditional GET request? Second, Indy 9 is ancient; please upgrade to version 10. As for why it's timing out, I don't know. Use the debugger to see what's happening, and work your way backward to see why Indy decides a timeout has occurred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TIdHTTP` in Indy 9 does not support conditional `GET` requests.  `TIdHTTP` in Indy 10 does, and some of the overloaded versions of `Get()` have a new `AIgnoreReplies` parameter that you can pass `304` to if `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exceptions are being raised.